# Singly linked list with generics and comparable data - corrected code

Tags: java, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I am currently reading about the thread-safe implementation of a linked list. I would like someone to point out some mistakes that will create issues if I try to make it thread-safe in the future.

I've corrected the buggy code from my [original post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94351/singly-linked-list-with-generics-and-comparable-data).

Information:

1. Please review the `SinglyLinkedList` mainly.
2. You may point out any design issue in classes or suggest another function that should be implemented.
3. I have written the code for practice purpose only. I know its not Java-linked-list compatible.
4. I tried to apply all the test cases. Please don't answer if you found another bug; just mention it in a comment. I will introduced it in test cases then get reviewed.

**`SinglyLinkedList`**:

```
package com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist.implemtations;

import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist.ILinkedList;
import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist.ILinkedListNode;
import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist.LinkedListerTraverser;

public class SinglyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> implements ILinkedList<T> {

  ILinkedListNode<T>       root      = null;
  ILinkedListNode<T>       last      = null;
  int                      size      = 0;
  LinkedListerTraverser<T> traverser = new LinkedListerTraverser<T>(root, size);

  @Override
  public ILinkedListNode<T> getRoot() {
    return root;
  }

  @Override
  public LinkedListerTraverser<T> getTraverser() {
    traverser.setRoot(root, size);
    return traverser;
  }

  @Override
  public void prepend( T data ) {
    if ( this.root == null ) {
      append(data);
      return;
    }
    size++;
    ILinkedListNode<T> node = new NodeImpl<T>(data);
    node.setNext(this.root);
    this.root = node;
  }

  @Override
  public void append( T data ) {
    size++;
    ILinkedListNode<T> node = new NodeImpl<T>(data);
    if ( this.root == null ) {
      this.root = node;
      this.last = node;
      return;
    }
    this.last.setNext(node);
    this.last = node;
  }

  @Override
  public void remove( T data ) {
    ILinkedListNode<T> parent = null;
    ILinkedListNode<T> node = root;
    ILinkedListNode<T> child = root.getNext();
    if ( root != null && root.getData() == data ) {
      root = root.getNext();
      size--;
      return;
    }
    while (node.getData() != data) {
      if ( node.getNext() == null ) {
        return;
      }
      parent = node;
      node = node.getNext();
      child = node.getNext();
    }
    parent.setNext(child);
    node.setNext(null);
    size--;
  }

  @Override
  public void insertAfter( int index, T data ) {
    if ( index < 0 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Negative Index not accepted.");
    }
    if ( index > size ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Out of Bound Exception.");
    }
    if ( index == 0 ) {
      this.prepend(data);
      return;
    }
    ILinkedListNode<T> node = root;
    while (node != null && index > 1) {
      index--;
      node = node.getNext();
    }
    size++;
    ILinkedListNode<T> newNode = new NodeImpl<T>(data);
    newNode.setNext(node.getNext());
    node.setNext(newNode);
  }

  @Override
  public T find( T data ) {
    ILinkedListNode<T> node = root;
    while (node != null) {
      if ( node.getData().compareTo(data) == 0 ) {
        return node.getData();
      }
      node = node.getNext();
    }
    return (node == null) ? null : node.getData();
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
    return size;
  }


  class NodeImpl<E extends Comparable<E>> implements ILinkedListNode<E> {

    private ILinkedListNode<E> nextNode;
    private E                  data;

    public NodeImpl( E data ) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ILinkedListNode<E> getNext() {
      return this.nextNode;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNext( ILinkedListNode<E> node ) {
      this.nextNode = node;
    }

    @Override
    public E getData() {
      return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void setData( E data ) {
      this.data = data;
    }
  }
}
```

**Helper classes**

**Test cases**

```
package com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist;

import com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist.implemtations.SinglyLinkedList;

public class LinkedListTester {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {





    // ============== APPEND TESTING =================//
    System.out.println("Test Case 1: Appending 1 element.");
    ILinkedList<Integer> LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(1);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 1 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 2: Appending multiple element.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(1);
    LT.append(2);
    LT.append(3);
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 5 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };




    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 3: Null List");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 0 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };




    // ============== PREPEND TESTING =================//

    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 4: Prepending 1 element.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.prepend(1);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 1 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };


    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 5: Prepending many element.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.prepend(5);
    LT.prepend(4);
    LT.prepend(3);
    LT.prepend(2);
    LT.prepend(1);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 5 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 6: prepend and append together.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.prepend(3);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.prepend(2);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.prepend(1);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.prepend(0);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 8 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };




    // ============== REMOVE TESTING =================//
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 7: Remove some Element.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(3);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.remove(3);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 3 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 8: Remove root element.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.remove(4);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 0 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 9: Remove last element.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.append(8);
    LT.remove(8);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 5 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 10: Remove All element.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.append(10);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.append(8);
    LT.remove(8);
    LT.remove(7);
    LT.remove(5);
    LT.remove(4);
    LT.remove(6);
    LT.remove(10);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 0 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 11: Remove element not existing.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.append(10);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.append(8);
    LT.remove(41);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 6 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };




    // ============== FIND TESTING =================//
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 12: find element at root.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.append(10);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.append(8);
    Integer a = new Integer(4);
    System.out.println(LT.find(a));
    if ( a.compareTo(LT.find(a)) != 0 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in find.");
    };
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 6 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };




    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 13: find element at last.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.append(10);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.append(8);
    a = new Integer(8);
    System.out.println(LT.find(a));
    if ( a.compareTo(LT.find(a)) != 0 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in find.");
    };
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 6 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 14: find element non existing.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.append(10);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.append(7);
    LT.append(8);
    a = new Integer(21);
    System.out.println(LT.find(a));
    if ( LT.find(a) != null ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in find.");
    };
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
    if ( LT.size() != 6 ) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
    };




    // ============== INSERT AFTER TESTING =================//
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 15: Inserting at negative index.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    try {
      LT.insertAfter(-3, 5);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if ( e.getMessage() != "Negative Index not accepted." ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in Size.");
      }
      System.out.println("Tested");
    }
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();





    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 16: Inserting at 0 index.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.insertAfter(0, 5);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 17: Inserting at some index.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(1);
    LT.append(2);
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.append(6);
    LT.insertAfter(2, 3);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 18: Inserting at last index.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    LT.append(1);
    LT.append(2);
    LT.append(3);
    LT.append(4);
    LT.append(5);
    LT.insertAfter(5, 6);
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();



    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nTest Case 19: Inserting at Out of Bound index.");
    LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
    try {
      LT.insertAfter(4, 5);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      if ( e.getMessage() != "Out of Bound Exception." ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in insertion.");
      }
      System.out.println("Tested");
    }
    LT.getTraverser().traverseList();
  }
}
```

**Interfaces**

**`ILinkedList`**

```
package com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist;

/**
 * @author jaspinder
 *
 */
public interface ILinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  public LinkedListerTraverser<T> getTraverser();
  public void prepend( T data );
  public void append( T data );
  public void remove( T data );
  public int size();
  public void insertAfter( int index, T data );
  public T find( T data );
  public ILinkedListNode<T> getRoot();
}
```

**`ILinkedListNode`**

```
package com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist;

public interface ILinkedListNode<T extends Comparable<T>> {
  public ILinkedListNode<T> getNext();
  public void setNext( ILinkedListNode<T> node );
  public T getData();
  public void setData( T data );
}
```

**Traverser**

**`LinkedListerTraverser`**

```
package com.atleyvirdee.myDataStructures.linkedlist;

public class LinkedListerTraverser<T extends Comparable<T>> {

  ILinkedListNode<T> root = null;
  int                size = 0;

  public LinkedListerTraverser( ILinkedListNode<T> root, int size ) {
    this.root = root;
    this.size = size;
  }

  public LinkedListerTraverser( ILinkedListNode<T> root ) {
    this.root = root;
    this.size = -1;
  }

  public void setRoot( ILinkedListNode<T> root, int size ) {
    this.root = root;
    this.size = size;
  }

  public void setRoot( ILinkedListNode<T> root ) {
    this.root = root;
    this.size = -1;
  }

  public void traverseList() {
    ILinkedListNode<T> node = root;
    if ( node == null ) System.out.println("Empty List.");
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    size = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (node != null) {
      output.append("Element @ " + i + " = " + node.getData().toString() + "\n");
      i++;
      size++;
      node = node.getNext();
    }
    System.out.println("Size of List: " + size);
    System.out.println(output.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll just focus on one method:

> ```
>   @Override
>   public T find( T data ) {
>     ILinkedListNode<T> node = root;
>     while (node != null) {
>       if ( node.getData().compareTo(data) == 0 ) {
>         return node.getData();
>       }
>       node = node.getNext();
>     }
>     return (node == null) ? null : node.getData();
>   }
> ```

As pointed out in [my answer to another of your questions](/a/96695/9357), requiring the nodes to be `Comparable` is an unreasonable burden.  If all you want to check is equality, then call `node.getData().equals(data)` — *every* Java object has a `.equals()` method.

Naming interfaces with the `I…` Hungarian prefix is unconventional for Java; it's more appropriate in C#.

For a linked list, the conventional terminology is "head" instead of "root".

The only way that the last line is reachable is if `node` is `null`.  You don't need to test the `while`-loop condition again.  I suggest writing it as a `for` loop instead, to make the pattern more easily recognizable:

```
@Override
public T find(T data) {
    for (LinkedListNode<T> node = head; node != null; node = node.getNext()) {
        if (node.getData().equals(data)) {
            return node.getData();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Not using "I" - okay. Is there any naming conventions in Java? something like this - Just curious.
You are correct. I can change the last line.
Why to use for loop? not while? did not get that point.

Comment: As a general rule, if you can fill in all three fields of `for (init; test; update)`, then a `for` loop is better than a `while` loop, since you can see the loop structure at a glance just by looking at the loop header.

Comment: [Interface naming](http://stackoverflow.com/q/541912/1157100). Sometimes interfaces are named `Fooable`, with the "-able" suffix suggesting that it can do something.

Comment: So one should use for loop instead of while in general? Because it's more readable?

Comment: Every while loop can also be written as a for loop; every for loop can be written as a whole loop. The general rule is, if it fits the for-loop pattern (init; test; update), such that the loop header would meaningfully describe how the loop works, then write it as a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

While `reinventing-the-wheel` is often fun, you needn't go that far when exercising. Even when writing your own `SinglyLinkedList`, you should try to fit it to the existing interface `List`. This way you both exercise programming and learn about existing classes.

There's no `equals` and no `hashCode`. You really should write them.

## SinglyLinkedList

```
  ILinkedListNode<T>       root      = null;
  ILinkedListNode<T>       last      = null;
  int                      size      = 0;
```

This looks more like a fill-in form than like a Java code. If you want a table, use a spreadsheet.

- It adds no value to your code and just costs time.
- It also breaks after renaming.
- Moreover, it makes problem together with version control (e.g., `git`) as it may force you to introduce needless changes (just imagine you use some `reallyLongNameNotFittingInYour` column.

Explicitly initializing fields to their default values buys you nothing. Just leave it out, there's no risk involved in

```
  ILinkedListNode<T> root;
  ILinkedListNode<T> last;
  int size;
```

This makes it also easier to spat the places where you do some non-default initialization.

---

```
  @Override
  public ILinkedListNode<T> getRoot() {
    return root;
  }
```

Look at `java.util.LinkedList`. It has a `Node`, but keeps it private. Always keep everything as much private as possible.

---

```
  LinkedListerTraverser<T> traverser = new LinkedListerTraverser<T>(root, size);

  @Override
  public LinkedListerTraverser<T> getTraverser() {
    traverser.setRoot(root, size);
    return traverser;
  }
```

This is probably wrong. You're reusing a traverser, so that there can be just one per list. Something like

```
for (String s1 : list) {
    for (String s2 : list) {
        ...
    }
}
```

wouldn't work with your list, even when you turned your traverser into an `Iterator`.

---

```
  throw new RuntimeException("Negative Index not accepted.");
```

Should be `IllegalArgumentException` or better `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

## LinkedListTester

```
public class LinkedListTester {
```

Use JUnit. It's not hard to learn and everybody uses it (or some better but similar alternative).

```
System.out.println("Test Case 1: Appending 1 element.");
```

You really don't want to print anything when you run thousands of tests.

```
ILinkedList<Integer> LT = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
```

`LT` is a wrong name, it should start lowercase and why "T"? Just call it `List`.

---

Rewriting you whole test with JUnit should take 10 minutes at most. This is the start

```
public class LinkedListTest extends TestCase {
    public void testAppend_one_element() {
        ILinkedList<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
        list.append(1);
        list.getTraverser().traverseList();
        assertEquals(1, list.size());
    }

    ...
}
```

As you can see, naming methods in tests is not that strict. It's usually `test` + capitalized method name and you may add an underscore and some details. Some people call their methods like `test_that_adding_two_and_three_gives_five`.

No idea what the traverser does in the above test. If you implemented `List` and used Guava, you could simplify your test to

```
    public void test_appending_one_element() {
        ILinkedList<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<Integer>();
        list.append(1);
        assertEquals(ImmutableList.of(1), list);
    }
```

which is more descriptive.

## LinkedListerTraverser

It looks like all it does is printing. Implement `toString` in your list (you may need a helper class for this, but probably not).